# Картина в jar файле

Tags: java, jar

Как правильно добавить картинку в проект java. При отладке картинка отображается, но после сборки проекта в jar, картинки нет.

```
systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src\\images\\logo-main2.png");


    TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image , "GrindFM", popupMenu);
    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
    systemTray.add(trayIcon);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Положите картинку в пакет и укажите абсолютный путь к картинке начиная с корня пакетов: /mypackageroot/myblablabla/image.png

Comment: Не совсем понял, какой будет путь в моем случае?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы загружаете ресурс с диска, а не с jar'ника. Когда вы работаете в dev окружении, вы запускаете jar'ник оттуда, откуда можно пройти по папкам на диске и дойти до этой картинки. Когда вы запускаете это на другом ПК, то там соответственно этой папки нет. Вам нужно использовать загрузку ресурсов из `classpath`, для этого поменяйте код следующим образом

```
systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

URL resource = getClass().getResource("images/logo-main2.png");
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(resource);

TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image , "GrindFM", popupMenu);
trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
systemTray.add(trayIcon);
```

Все должно заработать

Comment: перенес по такому пути, всеровно не отображается в jar
 Image image = new ImageIcon("src\\java\\resources\\logo-main2.png").getImage();

Comment: Теперь эта картинка попала в class path, загружать надо теперь её из class path, вы загружаете с диска, картинку jar 'ник ищет снаружи себя, а не внутри, а когда будете грузить из class path, то будет искать внутри

Comment: Можете поподробней как из class path грузить.
Я добавил 
String path = "/resources/logo-main2.png";
PlayerRadio.class.getResourceAsStream(path);

Comment: Почти правильно, в вашем примере надо убрать /resources, и оставить просто logo-main2.png

Comment: String path = "logo-main2.png";
        PlayerRadio.class.getResourceAsStream(path);

        Image image22 = new ImageIcon("src\\java\\resources\\logo-main2.png").getImage();

        TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image22, "GrindFM", popupMenu);
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        systemTray.add(trayIcon);
Всеровно не видит картинку в jar

Comment: У вас getResourceAsStream вернул стрим? Вы можете его передать в Image Icon?

Comment: PlayerRadio.class.getResourceAsStream(path) возвращает null

Comment: А можете тут привести структуру ваших папок?

Comment: И проверить содержимое jar, на предмет нахождения в нем картинки и папки в которой она находится

Comment: В jar файле есть java/resources/logo-main2.png

Comment: А можете ещё приложить скрин каталогов в джарнике пжл

Comment: скрин в описание добавил

Comment: Сейчас попробую повторить у себя локально

Comment: Верните файл туда где он у вас был, я думал что вы собираете maven'ом. И загрузите файл вот так

`getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/logo-main2.png")` и передайте этот stream классу Image, чтобы он загрузил картинку из стрима

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77184/discussion-between-razear-and-vyacheslav-gusser).